# Realtime Online Eevee Viewer

Tags: eevee-render-engine

Can anyone suggest a strategy of getting this look that I attached in the image (from Eevee), into a realtime web environment, if I use sketchfab or GLTF im not getting the same look as the shader is a mix shader with SS and PBR texture sets.  [image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541

Comment: ok thanks, so if i understand, basically try gltf but even that contains just basic pbr export, otherwise remake the material in the target application.

Comment: Bingo. Or try Blend4Web or similar WebGL based solutions, but the issues will likely be the same as Sketchfab

Comment: yah thanks, would you suggest texture baking this material effect?  But then is there a release of texture baking eevee?